# What is equivalent to log4j 1 `log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Header=true` in log4j 2?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, syslog

I'm migrating a log4j.properties to log4j2.xml.  Syslog appender in the former has a configuration

```
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Header=true
```

What's the equivalent setting in log4j2.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to do anything:

In log4j 1, setting `log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Header=true` resulted in the [appender including the HEADER part (that is, timestamp and host name) of the syslog packet](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SyslogAppender.html#setHeader(boolean)).

In log4j 2, the [timestamp and host name are always included](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/xref/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/layout/SyslogLayout.html#L73). (Looks like this cannot be switched off.)